# iOS: Image view inside MapView

Tags: ios, imageview, android-mapview

I'm starting to iOS develop.

I have a `UIMapView`, and I want to show an image on the top of this `UIMapView`. But, when I drag a `UIImageView` to my `UIMapView`, the `UIImageView` superimposes my `UIMapView`. How can I set the position of the `UIImageView` to top and continue to show the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in interface builder. You might be able to do this programatically.

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[self.mapView addSubView:image];
```

You'll have to fix the origin of exactly where you want to place the image on the map however.